# convert values float to percentage keep the string values pythoon

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, try-catch, except

I try to convert just the float values to percentages and keep the *- values without change

```
[data['NPS'] = np.where(( data['Total']<= 3 ) , "*_", df['NPS'])][1]
```

I try [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KB6uL.png)to convert a total less than 3 after converting the percentage but I got an error the `ValueError: could not convert string to float:`
I also use try-except code to do it but it's not working
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQn6t.png)

Comment: Error reports should show the full error message.  It may help to break the `where` into pieces to identify the exact step.  There's a lot going on in that line.